# How to get HQ youtube thumbnails?

Tags: youtube-api

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

That works for small thumbnails.

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

That works for HQ but only 1 image. Question is how to get 4 HQ thumbnail images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Are you referring to the full resolution one?:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

I don't believe you can get 'multiple' images of HQ because the one you have is the one.

Check the following answer out for more information on the URLs: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

> For live videos use `https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault_live.jpg`
>
> - [cornips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763267/cornips)

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, but the link you gave to me is just for 1 maxresdefault.jpg image, how can i get 3 others in that high res?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Besides getting the other ones

Comment: So there's only one high res thumbnail?

Comment: Yea, not sure if the api can though. Looking into it a bit. Edit: I only found 1 highres thumbnail for the specified video id.

Comment: damn, i need 4 thumbnails (300x300 aprox), any advice?

Comment: hmm look farther into the API not sure if they'd have exactly what your looking for but that would be the place that would have it. Besides that I'm out of information haha good luck @Heihachi!

Comment: The maxresdefault thumbnail does not always exist.

Comment: is there any way to get thumbnail from audio file

Comment: This does not work for me. I tried: http://img.youtube.com/vi/tadyoeSn2xE/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @NameisNilay I suspect that is because your video is only available at 360p resolution.

Comment: How can we check if the max resolution thumbnail is available??

Comment: For live videos use `https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault_live.jpg`

Answer (score 27):

YouTube resolutions and images

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video-id>/<resolution><image>.jpg
```

**Resolution**
 - lowest resolution
sd - Standard Definition
mq - Medium Quality
hq - High Quality
maxres - MAXimum RESolution

**Image**
default - Default image (1, 2, 3 shot from video, or custom uploaded)
1 - First shot from video
2 - Second shot from video
3 - Third shot from video

Comment: This works. I don't understand why isn't this the accepted answer. No answer really provided that info which the question was is really about. WEIRD. What am I missing? for example, this works just fine: `http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video-id>/hq3.jpg`

Answer (score 12):

You can simply get HQ youtube thumbnails..

http://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: What's the difference between "maxresdefault.jpg" and "hqdefault.jpg"? I've noticed that while "maxresdefault.jpg" seems more commonly used, YouTube videos often don't have a "maxresdefault.jpg", but they usually have a "hqdefault.jpg".

Comment: Just noticed that (depending on the format thought) "hqdefault.jpg" adds black borders on top and bottom, whereas "maxresdefault.jpg" doesn't..

Comment: also maxres can be bigger than HQ.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the resolution you need, you can use a different URL:

Default Thumbnail

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

High Quality Thumbnail

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

Medium Quality

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

Standard Definition

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

Maximum Resolution

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Note: it's a work-around if you don't want to use the YouTube Data API. 
Furthermore not all videos have the thumbnail images set, so the above method doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get id from:

> youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID

And put it in:

> i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg

I hope that I helped :D